# In Android, how is it possible to make serial ports (ttyS0, ttyS1) r/w for everyone?

Tags: android

I've developed an app that listens to the serial ports and I've been using "chmod 666 /dev/ttyS0" for read/write access to the serial port - however - this method relies on "su" and is only temporary.

What needs to be done to gain read/write access to the serial ports permanently ?

Comment: Android phones have serial ports?

Comment: I never mentioned "phone", but check this device: http://www.technexion.com/index.php/arm/ti-sitara-am3517/tam-3517

Comment: Your link leads to "category not found". Why is internet so temporary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you will always require superuser/root access to do this on COTS hardware (but then most off-the-shelf Android devices don't have accessible serial ports).

If you are in control of the device firmware/ROM, you could potentially make other arrangements so that the init.rc file sets ownership of the serial device so that only your app has access, but this seems more difficult than probably necessary.

Your best bet is to require a rooted device, and your app will need to set the permissions on the serial device file every time before it is opened.  If your phone has the [su app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/superuser/com.noshufou.android.su) installed (which is typical for rooted Android devices), then your app can easily do this automatically.  The first time the app attempts to do this, the user will get a confirmation dialog, but they can check a box so that the decision to allow is remembered.

On a rooted device, you should be able to do something like:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c 'chmod 666 /dev/ttyS0'");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I came across this blog and I wonder how he decided he needed to edit "init.mahimahi.c". The "how" is important because I'd have to find an equivalent file on my system.  http://atechyblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/reboot-persisting-all-user-access-usb.html

Comment: I see your link above to a TI OMAP3-based system.  So you are probably using a [Rowboat](http://code.google.com/p/rowboat/)-based Android build.  So you likely just want to edit `init.rc` in the initramfs. Your existing one probably looks something like [this](http://gitorious.org/rowboat/vendor-ti-omap3evm/blobs/master/init.rc).

Comment: Yes, I pulled the init.rc from the device and it does seem to be the best place to script a chmod 777 of the appropriate ttyS. This led me to the next step: how do I identify what ttyS matches what UART ? There's 3 UART's on that device. Additionally, the init.rc script only does anything (chown) with ttyS0. However, /dev lists up to ttyS3. Where are the other 3 ttyS's created ?

Comment: My second question in the comment above basically asks the question "if I add a chmod ttyS3 to init.rc, will ttyS3 exist at the point in time when the init.rc is executed at bootup?". I theorize that ttyS1 through 3 represent the UART's on the device - but I can't be sure until I find a way to verify this assumption.

Comment: Run `dmesg` to determine when the ttySn ports appear.  If they appear early in the boot process you are probably fine and anyways I suspect they are just the integrated OMAP3 UARTs.  Kernel developers are usually sane, so I would just try UART1=ttyS0, UART2=ttyS1, UART3=ttyS2 first :)  I don't know what all hardware you have available to you but you could test these assumptions by hooking up a null modem to a PC if you have DB9 ports, or if not, hooking up a scope to the TX line of each and doing `echo blah > /dev/ttySn`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help others.

1. Find your init.rc file on your linux repo directory "root"
2. Put "chmod 666 /dev/ttyS0" to anywhere
3. Compile your Linux Kernel and get uImage
4. And you are ready to use your Serial Port

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a virtual serial port over USB? There are no physical serial ports on any of the Android devices I know.

About your question: you can't. Applications on normal (non-rooted) devices are [sandboxed](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html) and do not have privileges to invoke system commands like `chmod`.